# Rust URL remove specific GET parameters

Tags: url, rust

I have this URL as a `String`: `"http://blah.com/a/b?a=1&b=2"`.

How can I remove or replace the GET parameter for `b` or strip the parameters entirely using Rust?

The [`ParseOptions`](https://docs.rs/url/latest/url/struct.ParseOptions.html) of the url crate doesn't seem to give me anything for this.

Am I just limited to using String methods to find/replace?

Comment: I tried to modify the query. See my answer. There might be better ways, but it did the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rust
let mut url = Url::parse("http://blah.com/a/b?a=1&b=2").unwrap();
url.set_query(None);
```

You can also take the query as pairs and manipulate it
https://docs.rs/url/2.1.1/url/struct.Url.html#method.query_pairs_mut

Example how to update the query value for `b` (caution I'm a Rust beginner)

```rust
  use url::Url;
  fn main() {
      let url = Url::parse("http://blah.com/a/b?a=1&b=2").unwrap();
      let query: Vec<(_, _)> = url.query_pairs()
          .filter(|p| p.0 != "b")
          .collect();

      let mut url2 = url.clone();
      url2.set_query(None);

      for pair in query {
          url2.query_pairs_mut()
              .append_pair(&pair.0.to_string()[..], &pair.1.to_string()[..]);
      }
      url2.query_pairs_mut()
      .append_pair("b", "5");

      println!("New Query: {}", url2);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove all query parameters using [.clear()](https://docs.rs/form_urlencoded/1.1.0/form_urlencoded/struct.Serializer.html#method.clear).

```
let url = Url::parse("http://blah.com/a/b?a=1&b=2").unwrap();
url.query_pairs_mut().clear();
```

Replacing query parameters.

```
let url = Url::parse("http://blah.com/a/b?a=1&b=2").unwrap();
let query = url
    .query_pairs()
    .filter(|(name, _)| name.ne("b"));
let mut url = url.clone();
url.query_pairs_mut()
    .clear()
    .extend_pairs(query)
    .extend_pairs([(Cow::from("new"), Cow::from("8"))]);
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=292a61ffecebd92db09a9fc6519518fa)